# How can I transpile a folder with babel and still include files that are being imported from another folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

My backend folder is an `express` server that will run on a `Node.js` environment on the Cloud.

Here is my project structure:

```
backend
  // FOLDERS AND FILES FROM BACKEND
  index.ts
frontend
  some-file.js
```

I need to transpile my `backend` folder with `babel`, but it contain some imports from another folder. In this example: the `frontend/some-file.js`.

Obs: In my real case, it's a lot of files. Like `util` functions, common constants files, etc. I also transpile most of the frontend code in order to do SSR.

If I just do `babel backend/src`, it will only transpile the contents of `backend/src` and the `some-file.js` file will be missing.

Is there any way around this? I mean, how can I transpile a folder with babel and stoll include the imports that it makes from outside that folder (except `node_modules` for obvious reasons).

Maybe `@babel/register` would help? [Link](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register)

I could try to use `webpack`, but I get the feeling that this is not what `webpack` was designed for. Webpack implements a module system for the browswer, while Node.js has a module system, so it shouldn't need webpack.

How do people usually handle this?

Comment: ever find a solution?

Comment: @user1063287 I gave up on this and decided to do a mono-repo structure using yarn workspaces. You can also have a look into Lerna workspaces. But yarn workspaces is a simpler pattern and solved my problem. You can have a common package that you can import both from FE and BE. You'd have 3 (or how many you need) separate packages under the same project. FE, BE and common, for example.